# Reload page if tab reopened

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, browser

How do I reload the page if the tab is closed and reopened in browser ?

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT x FROM users WHERE id='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $x = $row[0];

    // value for x here is 50

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET x='100' WHERE id='1'";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Page content</p>
        <script>
            alert('<?php echo $x; ?>');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

First the alert says 50

Then I close the tab pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Then when I reopen the tab pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, the alert says 50 again instead of 100

What do I do to get the updated value?

Comment: The browser is showing the cached copy of the page. You need to click on the Reload button to go back to the server.

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do to make this happen automatically.

Comment: isnt there a way to load fresh php every time ?

Comment: Maybe it depends on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally if you reopen the same page within a very short time the web page will be loaded from the cache. Try to clear the cache and reload.

If you want your site to always load from the server without using the cache. You can add the following in your php script. But do not use this unless this is really necessary since the caching mechanism are in place to improve the user experience.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot man. just what i was looking for. it is **really necessary** to update for my application!

Comment: Anytime. Always happy to help